# Help with sitemap testing

Tags: seo

Generated Sitemap.xml has some object to be hidden. Trying to  modify profile's permissions so that only the desired Account record types display in the Sitemap as creating a custom sitemap is not a best practice as per SEO for Experience Cloud Sites FAQ doc.

Problem is after making changes to the profile permission how do I test this is in dev sandbox before making changes in staging or prod?

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't test in a Sandbox at the moment, you are only able to generate Sitemaps in Production.

See the Sitemap section here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_seo.htm&type=5